# How do you suggest I write in an archaic style?

Tags: writing, writing-style

I'd been exploring different styles of language when I decided I'd like to write in an archaic style as was common in the 18/19th century. How do you suggest I write in such style? Please do suggest anything you feel would be of particular benefit for my writing.

Comment: StackExchange shies away from questions whose answers will necessarily be more opinion-driven than definitive. With that said, you might have better luck asking this on [Writers.SE], though I can't guarantee it won't be closed as off-topic there as well.

Comment: I do think this is off-topic.  But how about getting some books written in your chosen style, study them, and then write like them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for general writing advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for writing advice that is general within the field specified.

Comment: You will not find this an easy thing to do. You may well need some training. A good start might be to begin by reading the Bible (KJV), for a 17th-century grounding, some of Daniel Defoe, (early 18th), Jane Austen (late 18th), and progress on to Charles Dickens, Thomas Hardy and Anthony Trollope (19th). Read that lot and you may well find you have a better ear for 'archaic' English.

Comment: @WS2 Austen drafted some of her novels in the late 1790s, but she later revised them; none was published before 1811.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, well. Early nineteenth then! (And I have only just driven within spitting distance of her family home at Steventon, Hampshire this very morning - and in the early spring sunshine too!).  For the 18th, try the works of Dr Samuel Johnson.

Answer (score 2):

Best to find an author whose style and subject matter closely matches what you wish to achieve, and immerse yourself in that style, noticing the lexis used, the way sentences are structured and the way in which formality differs from today's norms.

Comment: I would be leery of picking a single author.  Better to pick several from the same period and culture.